# Select the records which are common against all the possible values of another column

Tags: sql

A table say table1 has 3 columns.
Suppose the third column is city.
For city, a master table is there say city_master.
I want to select the records for table which is present commonly available for all the cities

Eg:

```
City_master contain C1 to C4 cities
```

Table1 is as below

```
Col1    cOl2   col3_city
ABC      123    C1
ABC      123    C2
ABC      123    C3
ABC      123    C4
ABC      211    C1
ABC      211    C1
ABC      213    C4
```

Here the expected should be first 4 rows(means col1 and col2 are commonly present against all the cities)

Answer (score 3):

First you should make a query with GROUP BY and find all Col1,Col2 that have COUNT of distinct cities the same as count of all cities in the `City_master` table. Then just JOIN it with the `Table1`

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 as T1
JOIN 
  (
     SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Table1
     GROUP BY Col1,Col2
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col3_city)  = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM City_master)
   ) as T2 ON T1.Col1=T2.Col1 AND T1.Col2=T2.Col2
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/508731/1)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

```
select col1, col2
from table1
group by col1, col2
having count(distinct col3_city) = (select count(distinct city) from table_city)
```

Comment: code only answers tend to get flagged - it helps to explain what needs doing, if only briefly.

Comment: I, personally, don't believe that I could have explained it better than it explains itself. There is no magic here. Entry level SQL... Chewing everything and putting into one's mouth is a disservice in my opinion.

Comment: Well someone else disagreed. All I know is I am seeing a strong uptick in otherwise valid code-only answers getting flagged for deletion when I am reviewing.